# Save rdd into mongo database using java

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, spark-streaming, rdd

I am attempting to save tweets in MongoDB using Java, This is what I have;

```
JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(
            3000));
    JavaDStream<Status> tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc);

    JavaDStream<String> statuses = tweets
            .map(new Function<Status, String>() {
                public String call(Status status) {
                    return status.getUser().getName() + ":"
                            + status.getText();
                }
            });

    JavaDStream<String> users = tweets.map(new Function<Status, String>() {
        public String call(Status status) {
            return status.getUser().getName();
        }
    });


    users.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<String>, Void>() {
        public Void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
            if (rdd.count() > 0)
                rdd.saveAsTextFile("storage/users/test" + rdd.id()
                        + "_.txt");
            return null;
        }
    });
```

Like you see I can store users in text file using rdd.saveAsTextFile but what I need is a way to save this rdd to a data base (MongoDB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [MongoDB Hadoop Connector](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop) to store save an RDD to MongoDB using `com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoOutputFormat`:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.set("mongo.output.format", "com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoOutputFormat");
config.set("mongo.output.uri", "mongodb://host:port/database.collection");
rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("file://this-is-not-used",
                           <keyClass>,
                           <valueClass>,
                           MongoOutputFormat.class,
                           config);
```

It may also be helpful to look at [an example project](https://github.com/crcsmnky/mongodb-hadoop-workshop/tree/master/spark) for how to do this.